# How to Vlookup or copy automatically the new inserted values in a row in excel to two merged cells in another sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data on sheet 1 for listing new tasks assigned everyday. On sheet 2 I want to automatically copy the new task name added in the new row of sheet 1 into two merged cells in sheet 2.

i used Vlookup to do this functionality but the problem is that I have to add an empty row between different tasks added in sheet 1 so that when I drag the formula of Vlookup from the first cell in sheet 2 till the end of the column, it would take all the values of the cells in sheet 1 instead of taking one and leaving the other.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a VBA code that can run continouosly to detect if a new task will be added to add an empty row but then hide it on sheet 1

Thanks

I have changed the way I wanted to do this by using the following code that is supposed to do the following: 
1.Detects if there is a change in Sheet 1 column A

2.copies the content of each cell in column A to two cells in sheet 2 in column D.

3.Merge between the two cells in column D

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
J=1
For i = 1 To 8
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D" & j).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value

Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D" & j + 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
J=J+2
Next i

With Worksheets("sheet2").Range("D" & j:"D" & j+1)
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.merge
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
```

---

1. The syntax of the range Range("D" & j:"D" & j+1) is not correct

how to do this ?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please post your code and where you're stuck and please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have changed the way i will do this by using the following script but i have issues with it

Comment: @Miqi180 I have amended the post

Answer (score 0):

The following code is the correct answer that finally worked :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
j = 1
For i = 1 To 50
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E" & j).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E" & j + 1).Value = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
With Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E" & j & ":" & "E" & j + 1)
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
.VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.merge
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With
j = j + 2
Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not an answer and should be added as an edit to the original post. Please delete,

Comment: In the previous code i am supposed to to modify the range as well that will b merged . its supposed to be ("D" & j : "D" & j+1)